# Laravel : Using WITH and left join filter table data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

On my query join 4 tables. I got all response but the three table which has a same field name 'title' and it is mismatch. So how can i solve this.Is there any way to filter filed which i want before `leftjoin` or after `leftjoin`  query.

My query look like :

```
  $userPost =  Post::with(['product','postattributes' => function ($query) {
                        $query  ->leftjoin('attributes', 'attributes.id', '=', 'post_attributes.attribute_id')
                                ->leftjoin('categories', 'categories.id' , '=', 'attributes.category_id');
                    }])->whereUserId($user->id)->whereStatus("Active")
                    ->get();
```

And response i gt :

```
 "postattributes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "attribute_id": 1,
                "post_id": 136,
                "created_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:28",
                "updated_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:28",
                "product_id": 1,
                "category_id": 1,
                "parent_id": null,
                "title": "Shape",
                "status": "Active",
                "sort_order": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "attribute_id": 2,
                "post_id": 136,
                "created_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:28",
                "updated_at": "2018-04-27 18:46:28",
                "product_id": 1,
                "category_id": 1,
                "parent_id": null,
                "title": "Shape",
                "status": "Active",
                "sort_order": 1
            } 
        ]
```

Now i want to use `title as category_title` on `categories` table.
how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` for this:

```
 $userPost =  Post::with(['product','postattributes' => function ($query) {
                    $query->select('categories.id', 'attribute_id','post_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at','product_id','category_id', 'parent_id', 'categoris.title as category_title', 'status', 'sort_order')
                          ->leftjoin('attributes', 'attributes.id', '=', 'post_attributes.attribute_id')
                          ->leftjoin('categories', 'categories.id' , '=', 'attributes.category_id');
                }])->whereUserId($user->id)->whereStatus("Active")
                ->get();
```

In `select` you can set all fields that you need, in this example I added all from your list.